# Array of strings as a attributes for new instance of a class - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, attributes

How can I pass a an array of strings as attributes when creating new instance of a class? Say I want to do something like this:

```
Person.new(person_attrs) #<= Wrong number of arguments. Expected 3, got 1
```

where `person_attrs.inspect` returns `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expecting a hash when setting the attributes to an object. You are getting the `Wrong number of arguments. Expected 3, got 1` error because it thinks the array as a whole is one argument (it does not care about it's contents).